# Moving on a mountain in the direction with the highest rate of change. (The mountain is given by an equation not $z=f(x,y)$).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> A traveler is standing on point $(1,1,0)$ on a mountain that is defined by the equation: 
> $3x^2y^3+2x^3y^2z+xyz^3=3$. 
> He decides that he wants to move from there in the direction where the rate of change of the height is maximum, in what direction in the space should he move in the start?

I've been faced with these type of questions alot whenever the "mountain" is given by $z=f(x,y)$. And then I know that the direction they asked about would be in the direction of $\nabla f=(f_x,f_y)$ and to decide the third component of the vector, I find the normal to the mountain in the point $(f_x,f_y,-1)$ and make sure $(f_x,f_y,-1)\cdot(f_x,f_y,c)=0$ and I find $c$. 
But here, the equation is making things hard for me, like, is $z$ a function of $x,y$? 
What I thought to do: 
$F(x,y,z)=2x^2y^3+2x^3y^2z+xyz^3=3$, so $\nabla F=(4xy^3, 6x^2y^2,2x^3y^2 )$ (I didn't compute any derivative with $z$ because $z=0$). 
And so that's a normal for the mountain $(4,6,2)$. 
but how do I find the gradient vector of $z=f(x,y)$? if I tried to do $z(2x^3y^2 + xyz^2)=3-2x^2y^3$, I can't really get it into the shape of $z=f(x,y)$. 
Any help is really appreciated in how to deal with this question. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already answered the question. Btw the equation in the question vs. what you are solving are different.

Comment: @MathLover I don't understand, how did I answer it?

Comment: The gradient is $(4, 6, 2)$ for the function you differentiated. So that should be the answer.

Comment: @MathLover the final answer is $(-12,-18,117)$, so I don't think that's the answer

Comment: my bad, the question says rate of the _height_ is maximum, I am assuming that is $z$?

Comment: @MathLover I'm not sure tbh, but I explained how I did it in questions where the mountain is given by $z=f(x,y)$. mostly struggling because it's given in an equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going by the equation in the question.

$3x^2y^3+2x^3y^2z+xyz^3 - 3 = 0$

Differentiating with respect to $x$,

$ 6xy^3 + 6x^2y^2z + 2x^3y^2z_x + 3 xyz^2 z_x = 0$

Differentiating with respect to $y$,

$ 9x^2y^2 + 4x^3yz + 2x^3y^2z_y + 3 xyz^2 z_y = 0$

Plug in $(1, 1, 0)$ to find $z_x$ and $z_y$.

Comment: OH! and that's basically my $(f_x,f_y)$??

Comment: That is correct. Whenever you come across such equations where you cannot separate $z$ easily, just do implicit differentiation. But the given answer does not seem correct. Check the equation once.

Comment: The equation is correct , the mistake was mine in finding the normal vector to the mountain, it should be $(6,9,2)$, and then I got the exact answer. Big thank you :).

Comment: ah ok, I knew something was wrong somewhere :)

Comment: I got one question if possible, and it's we know that $z$ is a function of $x,y$ because they're all in the same equation? like I could also say that $x$ is a function of $y,z$ and solve it the same way?

Comment: @Pwaol that is correct. That is why I asked what they meant by height. I could as well say $x$ represents height of the mountain. We then differentiate $x$ wrt $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127320/discussion-between-math-lover-and-pwaol).

Answer (score 1):

If you're given an equation of the form $f(x,y,z) = w$, then the partial derivatives of the variables with respect to each other are related by the triple product identity:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{wy}\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)_{xy}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\right)_{yz} = -1,
$$
where the subscripts indicate which variables are being held constant. In this case, we want the partials of $z$ that hold $w$ constant. That is,
$$
\nabla z = \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{wy} \hat{\mathbf{x}} + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{wx}\hat{\mathbf{y}} = -\frac{\partial w/\partial x}{\partial w/\partial z} \hat{\mathbf{x}} - \frac{\partial w/\partial y}{\partial w/\partial z} \hat{\mathbf{y}} = -\frac{\partial f/\partial x}{\partial f/\partial z} \hat{\mathbf{x}} - \frac{\partial f/\partial y}{\partial f/\partial z} \hat{\mathbf{y}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! could you explain how would you find $z_x, z_y$ in my question? that's part of my problem

Comment: Please don’t write meaningless stuff like partials with respect to $f$. You are mishandling the thermodynamics identity.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh hell, you're right, I explained this wrong. Fixing

Comment: You want the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ to define each of $x,y,z$ implicitly as functions of the other two.

Comment: @TedShifrin In this case you want to use the four-variable version to transform the derivatives into derivatives of $f$ rather than derivatives of $x$ and $y$, which are equally hard to find. Note that $f(x, y, z) - w = 0$ is an implicit definition of the relation among the four variables, even if $w$'s dependence is rather obvious.

Comment: With 4 variables, the product of the 4 partial derivatives is $+1$. At any rate, understanding your approach is harder than doing implicit differentiation in the first place. Can you actually derive your formulas?

Comment: @TedShifrin The product of 4 is indeed +1, but the product of 3 is still -1. Indeed, the thermodynamic identities usually use the four variables S, T, p, and V. The derivation proceeds according to the usual derivation--you ignore $y$ for one and ignore $x$ for the other. It's equivalent to implicit differentiation, but I find the triple product easier to remember.